# ffmpeg converting mov to mp4

Tags: php, ffmpeg

Trying to convert .mov to .mp4. Tried various suggestion codes on stackoverflow but nothing seems to be working.

```
`...muxer does not support non seekable output [48] => Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument [49] => Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- [50] => Conversion failed! ) 1`
```

I've tried various codec properties such as ac3, aac, libvo_aacenc

```
exec('
/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -y -i https://***.***.com/assets/regions/region-1/input.mov' . 
' -c:a ac3 ' 
. 'https://***.***.com/assets/regions/region-1/output.mp4' 
. ' 2>&1', $out, $res);

$modx->log(modX::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR, print_r($out));
$modx->log(modX::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR, $res);

return true;
```

Comment: From the output your getting, I would assume that you will need to write the file to local storage and then upload it to whatever service you want to.  Writing it directly to a remote http location doesn't look as though it will work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25443097/ffmpeg-redirecting-mp4-muxed-data-to-socket may have something useful.

Answer (score 0):

This is my custom batch to lossless convert my mov to mp4 by preserving file creation date:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

for /d %%D in (*) do (
    for %%B in ("%%D\*.mov") do ( 
        echo %%B
        if not exist "%%B.mp4" (
            ECHO Last-Modified Date   : %%~tB
            ffmpeg -y -i "%%B" -vcodec copy -acodec copy "%%D\%%~nB.mp4"
            powershell -Command "& { (Get-ChildItem %%D\%%~nB.mp4).LastWriteTime = (Get-ChildItem %%B).LastWriteTime ;}"
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: See also `-map_metadata 0` to simply copy create date tags. Last modified is _file_ metadata not _media_ metadata.